# Wpf combo box not being populate with sqlite data

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, combobox

I have wpf combo box which I am trying to fill using the following codes. I found these exact codes from another stack follow here [Attach a SQL database to ComboBox.ItemSource (WPF)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867647/attach-a-sql-database-to-combobox-itemsource-wpf). Nothing gets populate into the combo box. I also would like to what code can I use to set selected value if I provide some value based on the companyID.

```
        private void fillComboBox()
        {

            try
            {
                getCon getMyCon1 = new getCon();
                SQLiteConnection con = getMyCon1.GetConnection();
                SQLiteCommand sqlcmd = new SQLiteCommand();
                SQLiteDataAdapter sqladp = new SQLiteDataAdapter();
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();


                sqlcmd.Connection = con;
                sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                sqlcmd.CommandText = "Select * from company";
                sqladp.SelectCommand = sqlcmd;
                sqladp.Fill(ds, "defaultTable");
                DataRow nRow = ds.Tables["defaultTable"].NewRow();
                nRow["companyName"] = "Select A Company";
                nRow["companyID"] = "-1";
                ds.Tables["defaultTable"].Rows.InsertAt(nRow, 0);
                companyName.DataContext = ds.Tables["defaultTable"].DefaultView;
                //
                companyName.DisplayMemberPath = ds.Tables["defaultTable"].Columns[0].ToString();
                companyName.SelectedValuePath = ds.Tables["defaultTable"].Columns[1].ToString();

            }
            catch (Exception expmsg)
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                //sqladp.Dispose();
                //sqlcmd.Dispose();
            }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `ItemsSource` of `companyName`, you are now setting only `DataContext`.

`companyName.ItemsSource = ds.Tables["defaultTable"].DefaultView;`

Comment: Hi Anjum I got the list of item in the combo box now when I your as the last line. But it comes out all the id value e.g. -1, 1, 2,3 not the column companyName. Another thing I want to set first time selected as the -1 ? How to set that?

Comment: what you want to show in the combobox ? you have to set that column name as your DisplayMemberPath.

Comment: I want to show the companyName as the display member and the value to add into the db as companyID.

Comment: Set the column corresponding to `CompanyName` as `DisplayMemberPath`. Bind either `SelectedValue` or `SelectedItem` to some property in your ViewModel. If you want to use `SelectedValue` then set `SelectedValuePath` to CompanyId col name.

Comment: I have change to these lines 
                companyName.DisplayMemberPath = ds.Tables["defaultTable"].Columns["companyName"].ToString();
                companyName.SelectedValuePath = ds.Tables["defaultTable"].Columns["companyID"].ToString(); Can you confirm if I did it right? Also another thing do i need this companyName.DataContext or I can remove it ?

Comment: those lines are ok, now you need to use SelectedValue={Binding ChosenCompayId}, then when you select a company ChosenCompanyId will get the id of the company. for this binding to take place, you have to use DataContext too. So, set DataContext as doing now and set ItemsSource as ItemsSource={Binding} or {Binding .} .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100209/discussion-between-user5313398-and-anjumskhan).

Comment: I dont quite get you on this  "Bind either SelectedValue or SelectedItem to some property in your ViewModel. If you want to use SelectedValue then set SelectedValuePath to CompanyId col name" ? Because I tried this on button click could capture via this  MessageBox.Show("compan name is" + companyName.SelectedValue); I can even set the selectedValue via this same was companyName.SelectedValue=2? Is this a right or wrong method?

Comment: @user5313398 come in chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100209/discussion-between-user5313398-and-anjumskhan