# Filling WPF Combobox with SQL Column

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, xaml, user-interface

Going off of this thread: [Attach a SQL database to ComboBox.ItemSource (WPF)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867647/attach-a-sql-database-to-combobox-itemsource-wpf)

I am still confused on how to execute. Below is my code for my GUI. I am new to C# and am unsure how to manipulate the combo box.

I am trying to take data from a SQL query and fill the values of a combobox.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace List
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var instance = new SQLInformation();
            instance.fillComboBox("Data Source=server Initial Catalog=db; User id=user; Password=pass;", System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox. , "select distinct [location] from [dbo].[locations]", null, "[location]");
        }
    }

}
```

SQL Information code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Configuration;


namespace List
{
    public class SQLInformation
    {
        public bool fillComboBox(string connectionString, System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox combobox, string query, string defaultValue, string itemText)
        {
            SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand();
            SqlDataAdapter sqladp = new SqlDataAdapter();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();


            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection _sqlconTeam = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connectionString].ConnectionString))
                {
                    sqlcmd.Connection = _sqlconTeam;
                    sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    sqlcmd.CommandText = query;
                    _sqlconTeam.Open();
                    sqladp.SelectCommand = sqlcmd;
                    sqladp.Fill(ds, "defaultTable");
                    DataRow nRow = ds.Tables["defaultTable"].NewRow();
                    nRow[itemText] = defaultValue;
                    ds.Tables["defaultTable"].Rows.InsertAt(nRow, 0);
                    combobox.DataContext = ds.Tables["defaultTable"].DefaultView;

                    combobox.DisplayMemberPath = ds.Tables["defaultTable"].Columns[0].ToString();
                    combobox.SelectedValuePath = ds.Tables["defaultTable"].Columns[1].ToString();
                }
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception expmsg)
            {
                return false;
            }
            finally
            {
                sqladp.Dispose();
                sqlcmd.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="List.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="FirstWindow" Height="390" Width="683">
    <Window.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint='0,0' EndPoint='0,1'>
            <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                <GradientStop Color='#FFC1C1C1' Offset="0.99" />
                <GradientStop Color='White' />
                <GradientStop Color="#FFE4E4E4" Offset="0.397"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFD1D1D1" Offset="0.777"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Window.Background>
    <Grid>        
        <Grid Height="360" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" Margin="119,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="270" Source=""/>
            <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="153,50,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="209" Source=""/>

            <ComboBox x:Name="LocationComboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="153,122,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="73" SelectedIndex="0">

            </ComboBox>

        </Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are approaching this the wrong way. WPF was designed to work well using data binding and the MVVM methodology (Model->View->ViewModel). You should do some reading up on MVVM, as it is very powerful and will help you write better WPF apps. Your Window XAML file should just have layout code, and each property that you want bound to some data should use a {Binding} expression in the XAML.

For example, if you want to bind this ComboBox to a list of locations, you can use this XAML:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Locations}" />
```

And then in your ViewModel class, you can expose a property called Locations that returns a list of the locations from the database, like this:

First create a ViewModel class and implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface:

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
```

Then inside the class you'll add a public Property called Locations:

```
    private ObservableCollection<string> _locations;
    public ObservableCollection<string> Locations
    {
        get { return _locations; }
        set
        {
            _locations = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Locations"));
        }
    }
```

Notice how I've implemented the INotifyPropertyChanged interface on my ViewModel class. This interface is used by WPF to update the UI whenever a property on the underlying model changes. You can see where I am invoking the PropertyChanged event when my Locations list changes. This tells the UI that it should update any UI controls that are bound to Locations.

In the constructor of your MainWindow.xaml.cs file, you should set the DataContext to a new instance of this ViewModel:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = new MainViewModel();
    }
```

And this is what my final MainViewModel class looks like. You can replace my code with some real database code to populate the Locations list:

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<string> _locations;
    public ObservableCollection<string> Locations
    {
        get { return _locations; }
        set
        {
            _locations = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Locations"));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        // Load our locations from the database here
        // You can instead populate yours from SQL
        Locations = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        Locations.Add("Location 1");
        Locations.Add("Location 2");
        Locations.Add("Location 3");
        Locations.Add("Location 4");

        // Now your combobox should be populated
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I've had before and it worked flawlessly for manually inputting items. I got stuck when trying to add data from a SQL Server. Thus, I went an alternative route. I assume that I should store the SQL values in an array and then use a for loop to add them to the combobox using your prescribed method. Is this a valid direction?

Comment: No, you shouldn't be adding anything manually to the combobox. Populate the list of Locations from your SQL database. So create a SqlConnection, then a SqlCommand, then call ExecuteReader on your SqlCommand and read each record, calling Locations.Add(reader.GetString(0));. The UI will update itself whenever you add anything to the Locations list.

Comment: I don't think I was clear. I meant adding them one by one, as shown in your example. Nevertheless, I understand what you're saying. I'm going to try that and report back. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Yes, at some point you need to read your database records in one by one and populate the list. But at least using MVVM you are seperating your View from your Model, the model in this case is your Locations. If you can't figure out the SQL part, let me know and I will update my answer with the code to do it.

Comment: I'm getting this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k626bk8b.aspx on "PropertyChanged?.Invoke". However, on this site: http://danrigby.com/2015/09/12/inotifypropertychanged-the-net-4-6-way/ works fine.

Comment: You're probably not using .NET 4.6 where the ? notation on delegate invocation was added. .NET 4.0 for example, doesn't have this notation PropertyChanged?.Invoke()...

Comment: Alright, I've been trying to get this to work for awhile now on my own. I have the SQL information being read to the console. I'm failing on putting it into the combobox. Could you walk me through that step, please?

Comment: You need to learn how MVVM works. You'll need a ViewModel class that has a property IObservableCollection<Location> Locations. Then you'll have to set the DataContext on your View = an instance of your ViewModel. Then you can add each database location to this list of locations and the UI will update automatically. The sample I provided you works fine - my combobox is populated with the 4 locations. I suggest you do an MVVM tutorial for WPF and change their sample code to fit your needs.

Comment: I spent all of today going through a tutorial. I have it working perfectly for the locations combobox. I'm having trouble extending the code you gave me for multiple comboboxes. Can I show you what I have and you critique, please?

Comment: Sure, I will be happy to look at it @ChasenBettinger

Comment: What platform would you like to communicate through?

Comment: Try me on Google chat @ChasenBettinger

Comment: I cannot use Google chat where I am. Can you join me on a collaborative code platform? Link: https://kobra.io/#/e/-KNYYF6i7ezMYTIsn6dZ

Let me know when you're there.

Comment: For anyone looking at this answer later, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49107609/4573703) is a good reference for the `SqlCommand` part needed to populate