# Fill combobox from SQL database with specific parameter

Tags: c#, wpf

I have problem to get specific value from sql server with parameter can anybody explain me why it works on winfom but not on wpf and how i can fix it 
my code:

```
private void UpdateItems()
{
       COMBOBOX1.Items.Clear();
       SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.constring.ToString());
       SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM CLIENT where cod_cli='some_specific_string'", conn);
       DataSet ds = new DataSet();
       da.Fill(ds, "CLIENT");
       COMBOBOX1.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
       COMBOBOX1.DisplayMemberPath = ds.Tables[0].Columns["FR"].ToString();
       COMBOBOX1.SelectedValuePath = ds.Tables[0].Columns["FC"].ToString(); 
}
```

The program when execute this function crash with error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid column name
>   'some_specific_string'.'

Comment: SELECT * FROM CLIENT where cod_cli="some_specific_string" in this line " cod_cli" this column is not found in your table. Check query is execute in sql properly.

Comment: query is correct because in winform it works correctly and takes the correct values.

Comment: and i execute on sql server manager and it works the problem is on wpf  i cant understand why it works on Winform and not on wpf the code is same and same query

Comment: its a SqlException it have nothing to do with wpf. Mostly you were trying against wrong database. Make sure it connect to same both in wpf & winforms

Comment: i find the solution  `SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.constring.ToString()))
            {
                SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM CLIENT where cod_cli='cod_of_client''", sqlConnection);
                sqlConnection.Open();
                SqlDataReader sqlReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (sqlReader.Read())
                {
                    COMBOBOX!.Items.Add(sqlReader["FN"].ToString());
                }

                sqlReader.Close();
            }`

Comment: if i define cod_cli = 'some_text' it works    if i use cod_cli="+some_string+" doesn't work whyyyyyyy??????

Answer (score 2):

the solution is

```
SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.constring.ToString());
{
    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM CLIENTS where cod_cli=@cod", sqlConnection);
    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cod", cod_cli.Text);
    sqlConnection.Open();
    SqlDataReader sqlReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (sqlReader.Read())
    {
        COMBOBOX1.Items.Add(sqlReader["FR"].ToString());
    }

    sqlReader.Close();
}
```

The query doesn't recognize string as parameter  but adding as SQL parameter it works.

Answer (score 1):

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.constring.ToString());
conn.Open();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM CLIENT where cod_cli='some_specific_string'", conn);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds, "CLIENT");

//Populate the combobox
COMBOBOX1.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
COMBOBOX1.DisplayMemberPath = "FR";
COMBOBOX1.SelectedValuePath = "FC";
```

`where` "FR" and "FC" are existing columns in your `SELECT` Query.

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow; please add an explanation about your suggested solution, in particular why you believe it is better than the solution already provided; that will help people get the most benefit out of your answer